# What is p(biased coin given heads) in 2 Fair coin, 1 biased coin experiment

Tags: probability, naive-bayes

In ["Conditional probability with Bayes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxm4Xxvzohk) theorem in Khan's academy, in 2nd experiment, where author has 2 fair coins, and 1 biased coin, he tries to calculate probability of biased coin, after first test: Heads.

**Note**: A biased coin is one which gives heads 2/3 times, and tail 1/3 times

p(B) = probability of biased coin
p(B/H) = probability of biased coin, given its Heads.
p(H) = probability of coin being Heads
p(H/B) = probability of coin being Heads, given its biased
p(B and H) = probability of coin being both biased and heads.

Event 1: Pick: p(B) = 1/3   (Since he has 2 fair coins and 1 biased coin)
Event 2: Flip: Heads: p(H/B) = 2/3  (Since a biased coin gives heads 2/3 of the time)
Now, what is p(B/H), that is probability being biased coin, given heads was outcome.

As per my understanding,
p(B and H) = p(H and B)

Thus
p(H and B) = p(H/B)p(B) = (2/3)(1/3) = 2/9
p(B and H) = p(B/H)p(H)

Now how do we calculate p(H)?
How does p(B/H) become 4/10?

Comment: I think you can just sum all the probabilities when you get H. p(H) = 1/2*2/3+1/3*2/3

Comment: Few people want to watch a 5 min video to find out what your question is. I would just cut the link and explain concisely what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sum all the probabilities that result in head (H)
\begin{equation}
p(H) = 1/2 * 2/3 + 2/3 *1/3 = 5/9
\end{equation}

And so $p(B|H) = 2/9 * 9/5 = 2/5$

Comment: your answer was spot on, and helped me understand bigger picture now. I have created an in depth article [here](https://parthibanrajendran.wordpress.com/2018/03/08/intuitive-approach-to-bayes-theorem/). Please check and share your feedback if time permits. Thank you for your timely help.